# loading Google Maps API V3 on Windows 8

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to make an app which can take two locations and display the route for it in windows 8 metro..!! the problem I am facing is that loading of GOOGLE MAPS API is not working..!! either synchronously or Asynchronously , I am giving valid API key and going along with the documentation provided and still getting a blank page in Async loading and getting a google is undefined error in sync loading of API.. kindly help

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>geoHelloWorld</title>

    <!-- WinJS references -->
    <link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0.RC/css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0.RC/js/base.js"></script>
    <script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0.RC/js/ui.js"></script>

    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <link href="/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/default.css"
        rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
                myOptions);
        }

        function loadScript() {
            var script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize';
            document.body.appendChild(script);
        }

        window.onload = loadScript;
    </script>
  </head>

<body>
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just wrote a tutorial about using the Google Maps API with Windows 8, http://www.creepyed.com/2012/11/how-to-use-the-google-maps-api-on-windows-8/. It has to do with how the script for Google Maps is called in the project and making sure you can get external content.

I was getting similar errors to you. I hope this helps!

Have a great day,
ed

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit of a newbie myself but I think you need:

```
<body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
```

instead of :

```
<body
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
```

Lea.

Comment: thanks..!! and sorry above errors were just typos and were done at sight, but problem is still there..!!

Answer (score 0):

close your `<body>` tag!
@LeasMaps,
`initialize()` calls on callback=? by the google api but he must remove the ()!

```
script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize';
```